# prove product of a reduced residue system is congruent to 1 mod $p^{\alpha}$

Tags: number-theory, reduced-residue-system

> Let $n=p^{\alpha}, p$ be an odd prime, $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Assume
> that $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ is a reduced residue system modulo $n$. Prove that
> $$x_1x_2...x_k\equiv -1\pmod{n}.$$

My attempt:
I have already shown that $x_1^2x_2^2...x_k^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}.$ So we have 2 cases here:
$$x_1x_2...x_k\equiv -1\pmod{n}$$ or $$x_1x_2...x_k\equiv 1\pmod{n}.$$
I'm stuck at the part proving  $x_1x_2...x_k\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ is impossible.
Could someone help me or have other ways to deal with the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can calculate exact formula for euler function $ \phi(n)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\{a_1,\dots,a_{\phi(n)}\}$ is a reduced residue system, what is $a_1\cdots a_{\phi(n)}$ congruent to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266351/if-a-1-dots-a-phin-is-a-reduced-residue-system-what-is-a-1-cdots-a) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x_1x_2%5Ccdots%20x_k%5Cequiv%20-1%5Cpmod%7Bn%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n%3Dp%5E%5Calpha%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aodd%20prime%2C%20OR%20content%3Areduced%20residue%20system&p=1). Note that $N$, the # of solutions to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, is $2$ in your ...

Comment: (cont.) case, giving the RHS is $(-1)^{N/2}=-1$. FYI, [Product of coprimes less than n](/q/2521376) shows the RHS is $-1$ if $n$ has a primitive root (which includes your $n=p^{\alpha}$ case), else it's $1$. In addition, the search also comes up with several other at least very closely related questions, such as [The product of integers relatively prime to $n$ congruent to $\pm 1 \pmod n$](/q/441667).